# Cucumber DuplicateStepDefinitionException

Tags: gradle, kotlin, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have two feature files: `first/first.feature` and `second/second.feature`.
Also, I have two step definitions files, which are in `package1` and in `package2` respectively.

So I can run first (or second) feature test with specific `glue` and `features` configuration.

But if I want to run both features I get `cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException`.

Can I create such configuration that enables me to run all my feature tests? Maybe with providing `glue`-`feature` pairs (or map?).

BTW I use this [gradle-cucumber-plugin](https://github.com/samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Cucumber works; all stepdefinitions will be loaded and cannot contain duplicates (or else, how would Cucumber know which to use). Tying your step definitions to a particular feature, is actually considered an anti-pattern: https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/anti-patterns/#feature-coupled-step-definitions
If the steps are in fact the same, consider merging your stepdefinitions. If they should in fact be different, consider using different language for each step.

If you do have a reason to run different features with different steps (for instance, one against a UI, another against an API), you could specify different runners with different configurations and run all the runners to run all the tests.

Comment: For anybody who might come into this truble: I used already two different runners but got the same error, whenever I started a test directly from within the feature file. I use IntelliJ. It truned out that the glue in the run-configuration was empty and IntelliJ would not use those stepdefintions under the same package but instead looking for all stepdefinitions from classpath downwards.

Comment: Note that you can specify the glue in the Run Configuration in IntelliJ